# RPMBUILD //SOURCES

Tags: rpmbuild

I'm trying to build a RPM for barnyard2-1.9, but when I attempt it I receive this error. These are the last few lines of the rpmbuild output:

```
+ /usr/bin/install -d -p /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/barnyard2-1.9-root/usr/share/doc/barnyard2-1.9/contrib
+ /usr/bin/install -d -p /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/barnyard2-1.9-root/usr/share/man/man8
+ /usr/bin/install -d -p /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/barnyard2-1.9-root/usr/share/doc/barnyard2-1.9/doc
+ /usr/bin/install -m 644 etc/barnyard2.conf /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/barnyard2-1.9-root/etc/snort/
+ /usr/bin/install -m 644 /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9//SOURCES/barnyard2.config /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/barnyard2-1.9-root/etc/sysconfig/barnyard2
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `/home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9//SOURCES/barnyard2.config': No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/rpm-tmp.66176 (%install)
```

RPM build errors:

```
Bad exit status from /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/rpm-tmp.66176 (%install)
```

I'm not sure where it's getting the "//" in "/home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9//SOURCES/barnyard2.config" line.
Here are the top few lines from rpm-tmp.66176 file:

```
RPM_SOURCE_DIR="/home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9//SOURCES"
RPM_BUILD_DIR="/home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9//BUILD"
RPM_OPT_FLAGS="-O2 -g -m64 -mtune=generic"
RPM_ARCH="x86_64"
RPM_OS="linux"
export RPM_SOURCE_DIR RPM_BUILD_DIR RPM_OPT_FLAGS RPM_ARCH RPM_OS
RPM_DOC_DIR="/usr/share/doc"
export RPM_DOC_DIR
RPM_PACKAGE_NAME="barnyard2"
RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION="1.9"
RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE="1"
export RPM_PACKAGE_NAME RPM_PACKAGE_VERSION RPM_PACKAGE_RELEASE
RPM_BUILD_ROOT="/home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/tmp/barnyard2-1.9-root"
export RPM_BUILD_ROOT

PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH

set -x
umask 022
cd "/home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9//BUILD"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it.
In my `.rpmmacros` file, I had:

```
%_topdir /home/snort/rpm/barnyard2-1.9/
```

The last `/` caused it. I'm not sure how `RPM_SOURCE_DIR` and `%_topdir` got connected, but whatever. It's working now.